# MySql carriage return

Tags: mysql

I am reading the MySql docs on string literals and tried the following with a carriage return:

`select 'i want a \r bannana';`

Why does this return:

```
+--------------------+
 bannana | 
+--------------------+
 bannana | 
+--------------------+
```

I would've thought it would output:

```
+--------------------+
 bannana | 
+--------------------+
```

or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line in the output is actually the column name as you have not explicitly defined how to return the result. You can modify your query and use 'AS' to specify your field name, like so:

```
SELECT 'i want a \r bannana' AS result;
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this one `SELECT 'i want you to give me a  \r bannana' AS result;` and it gave me this `bannana |ou to give me a`. Why is there column character in place of the 'y' in 'you'?

Comment: I assume you were using a linux command line with your query. Carriage returns and line feeds are handled a bit different by MySQL, depending on what operating system you use - and that simply messed up your output a bit. If you would run your query with just the linefeed, your output makes a bit more sense. Please try
    `SELECT 'i want you to give me a \n bannana' AS result;`
Now you should see the line break as expected, and the result decorated with a pipe before and after the output.

Comment: OS X uses \n (LF) as end of line character (as the system is UNIX based). Prior to OS X it was \r (CR) - which is now referred to as 'classic mac'.